# What is $e^{-\int \tan(t)dt}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that $-\int \tan(t)dt$ = $\ln |\cos t|$ (letting $C=0$). So I would think that $e^{-\int \tan(t)dt}$ would be equal to $e^{\ln |\cos t|} = |\cos t|$. However, my math textbook and Wolfram Alpha both say that $e^{-\int \tan(t)dt}=e^{\ln (\cos t)} = \cos t$. Why can the absolute value be ignored when taking the indefinite integral in this case?

Context: Finding an integrating factor for $x' = x\tan(t) + \sin(t)$. But Wolfram Alpha also gave me this answer without any differential equations context.

Comment: $\ln(-1) = i\pi$ for the principal value.

Comment: How do you **know** that $-\int \tan(t)dt$ = $\ln |\cos t|$? Everywhere I look shows it without the absolute value.

Answer (score 8):

*This is very subtle!!!!*

To see what's actually going on, you need to consider first, something you may not have noticed about indefinite integrals. What this arises from is a rather base mistake that seems to be perpetuated in a lot of textbooks, in particular, that ...

$$\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln |x| + C$$

or more generally, that

$$\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$$

This is NOT true, or more accurately, it is not general *enough*. It is only valid when $f$ is defined and continuous *on a connected domain* . Otherwise, if the domain is *dis*connected, that is, it is, say, a union $\mathrm{dom}(f) = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \cdots \cup I_n$ of pairwise disjoint *open* intervals $I_n$, then the function has "separate individual pieces" and you can translate those *individually* by *their own* constants $C_j$ and you will still have an antiderivative on the full, disconnected domain: the trick is that adding a constant doesn't change the derivative, but adding two separate constants on two intervals for a *connected* domain will make it non-differentiable at a point *if it introduces a break* , but *if there  is a disconnected domain* there is *already* a "break" in a sense and we can add different constants with no harm and no foul. In particular, if $\mathrm{dom}(f)$ has connected components $K_1, K_2, \cdots, K_n$ then

$$\int f(x) dx = F(x) + S(x)$$

where $S(x)$ is a *piecewise-constant* function defined on each piece of the domain:

$$S(x) = \begin{cases} C_1,\ x \in K_1\\
C_2,\ x \in K_2\\
\cdots\\
C_n,\ x \in K_n
\end{cases}$$

Thus for $\int \frac{1}{x} dx$ we should *really* have

$$\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln |x| + \begin{cases}C_1,\ x \in (-\infty, 0)\\
C_2,\ x \in (0, \infty)\end{cases}$$

because the standard domain $\mathrm{dom}\left(x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}\right) = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$, with two connected components $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$.

So with that in mind, let's think about $\tan(x)$. The function $\tan(x)$ has a domain that excludes *every odd integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$*: that is, $\mathrm{dom}(\tan) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{ \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$. This domain can also be written as

$$\mathrm{dom}(\tan) = \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi, \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)$$

thus having infinitely many connected components, namely the intervals $K_n = \left(\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi,\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)$ for every integer $n$. Thus we can associate an independent constant $C_n$ to each such interval for every such integer.

So what's up with $\ln \cos t$ and $\ln |\cos t|$? Well, the final piece of the answer involves *complex numbers*. It turns out you *can* take a logarithm of a negative number, thus you don't strictly *need* the absolute value signs; rather, your logarithm will simply be a complex number. In particular, for any real number $x < 0$, we have

$$\ln x = \ln(-x) + (2k+1)\pi i,\ k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

which as we see is ambiguous -- $\ln$ when extended this way is a "multi-valued function" (misnomer) or better "multi-valued association", much like the inverse trig, square root ($\pm$ square roots), etc. . (In fact, its multivaluedness is directly connected to that of the inverse trig "functions" by Euler's formula.) Of course now, just as how with those we have conventional "defaults" for what value to use, there is also a conventional "default" for this too and that is to take $k = 0$, giving

$$\ln x = \ln(-x) + i \pi = \ln |x| + i \pi$$.

called the "principal value" or "principal branch". Thus $\ln \cos x$ is a function which is real-valued when $\cos x$ is positive, and complex valued when $\cos x$ is negative, and undefined when $\cos x$ is 0. Furthermore, when it is complex valued, it is a *constant shift* of the absolute value function. That is, taking $\ln \cos x$ as antiderivative is equivalent to taking $\ln |\cos x|$ but with the function $S(x)$ such that it equals 0 on each interval where $\cos x$ is positive, and equals $i \pi$ on each interval where $\cos x$ is negative. If we take that $S(x)$, then we do indeed get $\ln \cos x$ as a valid antiderivative everywhere, AND furthermore we get the much nicer to work with integrating factor

$$e^{\ln \cos x} = \cos x$$.

Sweet :)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: The antiderivative is continuous in these cases as the domain is disconnected and it is continuous on each connected component. (This is another subtlety: it does not make sense to talk of, say, $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ having domain $\mathbb{R}$ (unless the codomain were something like the projective line), because by definition a function must assign exactly one, thus at _least one_ , member of its codomain to _every_ member of the domain. Such a 'function' would assign nothing to $0$.).)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : Nope, not if you want to be consistent with topological usage, which you should be, imo, otherwise you spoil the unity of math.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck : Well I'd think so, given that in the general topological usage, you talk of a continuous function from one topological space to another and there isn't restrictions like the "space must be connected" as part of the definition of continuity. The domain of the function is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so inherits its topology via the subspace topology.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: See, e.g. here: https://books.google.com/books?id=fvCpXrube5wC&pg=PA119&dq=continuous+function+topology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv28iYiaHUAhVWzmMKHe5fCLAQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=said%20to%20be%20continuous&f=false A topology textbook. Pg. 118. It defines continuity between two spaces, no mention of connectedness or anything else like that as a requirement.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Yeah it seems that calculus texts like to use a different definition of continuity, that is not necessarily compatible with the topological definition, but as I said it kind of spoils the unity of math.

Answer (score 4):

(integrating factor : $ \mu (t)$)

Then

$\ln \left | \mu (t) \right | = -  \int \tan(t)dt = \ln \left | \cos t \right |$

so $|\mu (t)| =|\cos t|$

It means $\mu (t) =\pm \cos t$

But $ \mu (t)$  should be differentiable. (When $\cos t \neq  0$)

so

Case 1: $\mu (t) = \cos t $ $(t \in R)$

or

Case2: $\mu (t) = - \cos t$ $(t \in R)$

A solution is $x = \frac{\int \mu (t) \sin (t) dt}{\mu (t)} + \frac{C}{\mu (t)}  = \mathbf{\frac{-\cos 2t +4C}{4\cos t}}$ ($C$ is constant) in both cases.

So, It is not important if $\mu (t) = \cos t $  or $\mu (t) = - \cos t$

Comment: $|a|=|b|$ does not imply $a=b$

Comment: The only _differentiable_ function $f$ with $|f(x)|=|\cos x|$ is $\cos$.

Comment: $f(x) = -\cos x $ is also differentiable

Comment: This may explain in the context of differential equation; but it does not explain why you can take the expression $e^{-\int \tan(x) dx}$ itself to be equal to $\cos x$ as Wolfram does.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is "Why can the absolute value be ignored?"

We have

\begin{eqnarray} e^{-\int\tan t\,dt}&=&e^{\ln\vert\cos(t)\vert+c_1}\\
&=&e^{c_1}\vert\cos(t)\vert
\end{eqnarray}

But $e^{c_1}>0$ for all values of $c_1$ and $\vert\cos(t)\vert\ge0$ when in fact solutions such as $-\cos(t)$ also exist. But the formulation $y=e^{c_1}\vert\cos(t)\vert$ excludes those solutions.

We can solve the dilemma by getting rid of the absolute value sign and replacing the positive constant $e^{c_1}$ by a constant $C$ which can take on values less than or equal to $0$. So we write

$$  y=C\cdot\cos(t)$$

Keep in mind that Wolfram also assumes that complex solutions are allowed.